# How do you limit the number of letters you scanf in a string?

Tags: c, string, clang, scanf

I got a string with the size of ten. How can I prevent an overflow when I scanf a string from the user? (i.e. if he types  "hello world!!" , it would just scanf "hello worl"

What I tried was : `scanf("%10s", w1)`

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10

void initWords(char* w1, char* w2, char* w3);

int main()
{
    char w1[N], w2[N], w3[N];
    printf("Enter 3 words up to 10 letter\n");
    initWords(&w1, &w2, &w3);
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", w1, w2, w3);
}

void initWords(char* w1, char* w2, char* w3)
{
    //scanf_s("%10s%10s%10s", w1,w2,w3);
    scanf("%10s", w1);
    scanf("%10s", w2);
    scanf("%10s", w3);    
}
```

Comment: better to use `fgets` in such scenarios

Comment: Use `fgets` instead of `scanf` `fgets` reads a whole line. And then do whatever you want with that line like truncating it.

Comment: What error? Can you post a [mre]?

Comment: I've never heard of said command/function

Comment: @Lostdawn never heard of what?

Comment: Really really depends on what function you use for taking input.

Comment: @SouravGhosh stack was corrupted

Comment: @Lostdawn [here you go](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

Comment: You need `%9s` to leave room for `'\0'`. Or make the buffer size `11`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Lovely ! that makes real sense and work perfectly

Comment: From the added code, `scanf("%10s", w1);` is lying to `scanf`. The size is not like `fgets()`. Read the doc for every function, not make assumptions.

Comment: Your `initWords` invoke from `main` is wrong as well. It should be `initWords(w1, w2, w3);` , and if your compiler isn't complaining with at least a warning you need to (a) turn up your warning levels to pedantic) and (b) not ignore them; rather, treat them as errors and *properly fix them*.